# Is using a URL to call AJAX from a hidden field XSS safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

Is it XSS safe to do something like this in jQuery?

```
<html>
...
<input type="text" id="message" value="" />

<input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value="http://www.mysite.com/ajax-server-code" />

<script>
var url = $('#url');
$.ajax({
url: url,         
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
$('message').html(data.message);
}
});
</script>
...
</html>
```

Basically, what I do here is:

- Use a hidden field to know which ajax URL to call
- Call the Ajax to the URL
- Use this data to change the DOM

Comment: This won't work since your variable 'url' doesn't contain the correct url, but it contains the hidden element. Change it to `var url = $('#url').val()`. For the question itself: it is never safe to use the value of a hidden field for this purpose, as the user can easily change the value of a hidden field.

Comment: the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) won't allow XSS.

Comment: XSS doesn't have to be loaded from an external URL; the policy just makes it harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea that's fine. I don't see any XSS problems with that.

Comment: Depends how the hidden field is populated, but it's probably safe.  If there was some way for a user to pass a GET variable which affected the contents of the URL due to some server side bug, then possibly not.

Comment: The field is populated from the server using server variables, not user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM is ediatble using the DOM Inspector in Firefox anyway, so you should never trust the browser to do or have what you think it should. Check any data you receive.

Comment: While true, it's not really relevant.  Modifying your own DOM is not really XSS.

Comment: Well, I guess that if you're able to modify the DOM in any way, the page is insecure. Using FireBug or any DOM editor doesn't make a page insecure or else every pages on the Web are insecure...

Comment: Pages are just output. It's the security of the application that matters.